# How do I select a div with a class name that ends with a specific string and keep the text content?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, puppeteer

So I'm using Puppeteer to scrap text from social media, I want to only scrap the text from a post, when I use the chrome developer tool to read what is the class name of the div which contains the text, it always displays a different class name when I reload the page but stay on the same post(see image)

[image: first page]

[image: second page]

But I noticed that the div class name always ends with `.text-content`, is there a way to select a div with only the end of the class name?

I tried to use the `$` selector like this :

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[class$='text-content']")
```

And yes it finds the correct div but if I try to use `.textContent` or `.innerText` it doesn't work and it returns undefined.

I also tried to select all divs from the developer console and then see if I could use the index of this div but it turns out that the index also changes every time I reload the page

What I wrote in the developer console :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div')
```

and then it gave me an array of divs but as I said I can't use that if the index changes every time.

Comment: Well, is there "last" element you're trying to hook with querySelectorAll? Have you tried "innerHTML" instead of "innerText"? Also you can use querySelectorAll like this `document.querySelecotrAll('.text-content')` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why your solution won't work

[`Document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) will return an HTMLCollection (an array-like element) so accessing to [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property will result in `undefined`, you should either use [`Document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or get the first index separately.

### Get individual element

Working example for demonstration:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[class$='text-content']")[0].textContent
```

```js
const content = document.querySelector("[class$='text-content']").textContent;

console.log(content)
```

```html
<div class="MuiBox-root jss1500 jss1169 js1499 text-content">This is the content</div>
```

or

```js
document.querySelector("[class$='text-content']").textContent
```

```js
const content = document.querySelectorAll("[class$='text-content']")[0].textContent;

console.log(content)
```

```html
<div class="MuiBox-root jss1500 jss1169 js1499 text-content">This is the content</div>
```

### Get all the matching elements

Also if you want to get all of the you can do a loop over the elements provided by `querySelectorAll` and the with the help of [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("[class$='text-content']");

Array.from(elements).forEach(element => console.log(element.textContent))
```

```html
<div class="MuiBox-root jss1500 jss1169 js1499 text-content">This is the content</div>
<div class="MuiBox-root jss1500 jss1169 js1499 text-content">This is the content 2</div>
<div class="MuiBox-root jss1500 jss1169 js1499 text-content">This is the content 3</div>
<div class="MuiBox-root jss1500 jss1169 js1499 text-content">This is the content 4</div>
<div class="MuiBox-root jss1500 jss1169 js1499 text-content">This is the content 5</div>
<div class="MuiBox-root jss1500 jss1169 js1499 text-content">This is the content 6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('text-content');
```

But do notice this returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). So you'll have to use accessors or iterate to get the elements contents:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('text-content');
// using acessor
console.log(elements[0].innerText);
console.log(elements[1].innerText);
// or iterating
for (const element of elements)
  console.log(element.innerText);
```

```html
<div class="something something text-content">aaa</div>
<div class="something something text-content">bbb</div>
```

Comment: This works but the page I'm working on has other divs with 'text-content' in the class and the one I need isn't always first so I can't use acessors

Answer (score 0):

You are actually quite close.

The classes are denoted by the . and these can be strung together.
So those random values you stung together are dynamic classes.

For usage on that `querySelector` you can have a look here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Armed with that knowledge you can easily pick up the elements you need.

```js
// Since you need only the one class:
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".text-content");

// Then you can get all of the elements matching.
for (let i = 0; i < elements. Length; i++) {

  // And easily do what you want with each.
  // Like getting or setting content.
  elements[i].innerText = "updated content";
}
```

```html
<div class="text-content other another">
  dummy content
</div>

<div class="text-content other">
  dummy content
</div>

<div class="other another">
  dummy content
</div>
```